# How to compare width and height of element with getSize() function with Protractor test?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Good morning dear colleagues.
I have a question about Selenium methods.
In my case I'm testing angular application with protractor and I want to compare returns value from `getSize` function with set values in the my test. Here is code below -

```
var searchForm = element(by.id('search'));

 it('searchForm must have width: 400px and height: 400px', function(){
  //expect(browser.driver.manager().window().getSize()).toEqual(400, 400);
  searchForm.getSize();
  searchForm.width.toEqual(400);
  searchForm.height.toEqual(400);

});
```

please help me to solve trouble. I hope you will help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Protractor `getSize()` function returns a promise with the dimensions object containing `width, height, hcode and class` of the element specified. Wait until the promise is returned and then resolve the promise to get the dimensions of the element. Here's how -

```
 it('searchForm must have width: 400px and height: 400px', function(){
    var searchForm = element(by.id('search'));
    searchForm.getSize().then(function(eleSize){
        console.log('element size: '+eleSize); //eleSize is the element's size object
        expect(eleSize.width).toEqual(400);
        expect(eleSize.height).toEqual(400);
    });
});
```

Also it is not recommended to write anything outside a spec `it` in automation using jasmine. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer is helped me enough, but I always recieved this massage: Expected Object({ width: 401, hCode: 1642496, class: 'org.openqa.selenium.Dimension', height: 480 }) to equal '{401, 480}'.
What is it: hCode: 1642496 ?

Comment: @Maksim did you try the code that i updated above? That error is coming out from the expect statement that you have used to check if the `eleSize` is equal to `{401, 480}`. Let me know if the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a usefull method for all kind of element attributes:

```
var elemHeight = element.getAttribute('height')
```

it returns a promise for the element's attribute, so you can use

```
elemHeight.then(function (height) {...
```

or just `expect(elemHeight).toEqual(400);` in your case

Comment: What is it: hCode: 1642496, class: 'org.openqa.selenium.Dimension' ?

Comment: @Maksim I would guess `hCode` is actually short for "hashCode", and not relevant really to JS usages of WebDriver. It's my (not very) educated guess that its a carry-over from some other language that WebDriver is written in or something.